# Layout above the google map breaks whenever autocomplete text view is clicked/used

Tags: android, google-maps, autocompletetextview

I placed a layout above the Google map. When I use the `AutoCompleteTextView` inside the layout, this breaks with some transparent/white lines.
[image]

How to stop the layout from breaking?

Xml is given below.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_10dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_10dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                    android:background="@color/pickup_divider_color" />
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/new_location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:hint="@string/collection_new_address"
                    android:textColor="@color/new_address_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/collection_update_location_text_size"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                    android:background="@color/pickup_divider_color" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide your xml?

Comment: you can assign your custom background

Comment: Without sharing your XML what do you think we are? Share your XML. I have also done the same thing in my app but layout never breaks even if the focus is on `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: hii,,Lalit Singh Fauzdar and  Jordy vd Heijden.   I shared Xml  with Question.please try and help.